# zebra datepicker - Direction to ignore disabled_dates

Tags: jquery

So I'm using this on a booking form. The form requires a minimum of 2 days padding to todays date, meaning you cannot submit a booking with less then 2 days notice.

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: [2, false],
    disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,6'],
    first_day_of_week : 0
    });
});
```

This is all fine when today is Monday - Thursday. If it's Friday - the 2 day direction allows the user to select Monday (as its counting the disabled Saturday + Sunday as days) but we need 2 working days not simply 2 days.

Anyone have any direction or work-arounds possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eneded up mangling together my own function. Feedback is welcome :)

```
/*
==================================================================================================
BookingForm - Datepicker
==================================================================================================
 */
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: [nextWorkingDay(), false],
    disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,6'],
    first_day_of_week : 0
    });
});
```

This the datepicker code calling nextWorkingDay function

```
/*  This function ensures that there is at least 2 working
    days before they are able to select a date. Without it 
    calling 2 days buffer in Zebra would include weekends meaning
    you could lob on Saturday and request Monday - needs to be Tuesday at earliest.
*/
function nextWorkingDay() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    //var mm = today.getMonth();
    var month=new Array();
    month[0]="January";
    month[1]="February";
    month[2]="March";
    month[3]="April";
    month[4]="May";
    month[5]="June";
    month[6]="July";
    month[7]="August";
    month[8]="September";
    month[9]="October";
    month[10]="November";
    month[11]="December";
    var MMM = month[today.getMonth()]; 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var theDate =  dd+'-'+MMM+'-'+yyyy;
    //All vars captured to do with todays date
    //Step through finding weekends

    var startDate = theDate; //"9-DEC-2011"
    startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
    var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 2, count = 0;
    while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
        endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
           count++;
        }
    }
    // Weekend found OR not found + 2 day buffer added to the date
    // Convert new date into bits + add padding to the month for Zebra usage
    var nextDate = new Date(endDate);
    var theDay = ("0" + (nextDate.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2); //Add padding to day
    var theMonth = ("0" + (nextDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); //Add padding to month
    var theYear = nextDate.getFullYear();
    //Format as required by Zebra
    var actualStart = theDay+'-'+theMonth+'-'+theYear;
    return (actualStart);
}
```